# I can't modify my JButton after having initialized it in the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jbutton

```
import javax.swing.;
import java.awt.;

public class Space extends JFrame {
   

    private JButton[][] jb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Space frame = new Space();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Space() {
         JPanel contentPane=new JPanel();
         contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
         JPanel p=new JPanel();
         contentPane.add(p);

         setContentPane(contentPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20));
        jb=new JButton[20][20];
        for(int i=0;i<jb.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<jb[i].length;j++) {
                jb[i][j]=new JButton();
                jb[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("i1.jpg")));
                p.add(jb[i][j]);
            }
        }
        JButton b=new JButton();
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("i2.jpg")));
        jb[10][10]=b; // when i set this cell, when i run, the icon of jb[10][10] didn't modified



    }

}
```

i tried that to modify my button jb[10][10] but when i run all button have the same icon, i want that the button share all values of b the icon too

i created a 20x20 matrice of button using gridlayout . And the problem is at the bottom, when i want to modify the button already initialized..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding,

> I can't modify my button ...

Yes, you can, but that is not what your code is trying to do. Inside your nested for loop, you have this line:

```
p.add(jb[i][j]);
```

which adds a JButton object that has already been created and placed in the `jb` array. So the JButtons in the JPanel *are the same ones that have been added to the 2D array*.

But later, change the object that the array element refers to here:

```
jb[10][10]=b;
```

When you do this, the JButton in the array at position [10][10] is no longer the same object, and so you are not "modifying the JButton" but rather are swapping references in one object that holds references to the JButton, the 2D array, *but not in the other object that holds references to the buttons*, the JPanel. So now the array and the JPanel have discordant references at that position.

Instead, to do what you desire, you must explicitly *change the state* of the button that already exists and is already held by ***both*** the JPanel and the array:

```
// *** not this ***
// JButton b=new JButton();
// b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("i2.jpg")));
// jb[10][10]=b;

// *** but instead THIS ***
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("i2.jpg"));
jb[10][10].setIcon(icon); // change the state, not the reference
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i want to change icon right, but i have right now a classe who extends JButton, who have a lot of attribut, so i want to modify the button to change all attribut not only icon, it is possible ? @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @Riské: yes it is certainly possible. But again, you shouldn't try to *swap objects* but instead need to focus on changing the state of the relevant object, the one that the JPanel already holds.

Comment: @Riské: but that is not what your original question asks, and this answer answers the original question fully.

Comment: @Riské: if your class extends from JButton, then it will have the same `.setIcon(...)` method, and thus the icon can be changed by calling the method.

Comment: i said that : I want that the button share all values of b the icon too. sorry my english isn't good. the solution is to have setter ? or we have an other solution ? @Hovercraft Full Of Eels i don't want only icon change, i want all my attribute change from the button, my question was not clear yeah*

Comment: @Riské: Your class already has a setter -- you should use it. If this doesn't answer the question, then your [mre] is not reflecting your true problem. Please let's not have a question with shifting requirements as this leads to nothing but frustration. All of your problem statements, requirements and relevant code, including the [mre] should be in the question itself. If calling setIcon on the existing reference doesn't work, then the problem ***is not in the code that you've shown***.

Comment: @Riské: but yes, change the state of the existing object. Don't try to swap references in one location in your code and hope that they will magically change elsewhere. Some programming language libraries, such as JavaScript frameworks like Vue and React, have reactive properties where you can do this sort of thing and it might work, but Java doesn't work this way.

Comment: ok i will set all my attribute from this existing object because we cant swap reference of object. I thought there was a technique shorter than that when you had a lot of attributes..@Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: Thanks you for your support ! Hope well  for you for next year